# Isn't Sunshine "THE ONE" mode not strong enough to fight The Demon King?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

So chapter 317 already release and there is a conversation between Escanor and Mael.

> [image]

I was shocked that Mael say that he cannot defeat the Demon King. But isn't Sunshine still have the ultimate mode called "The ONE"? If I recall, when it reach high noon, the holder of Sunshine can use "THE ONE" mode, which is "the invincible incarnation of power" based on Merlin.

So why Mael seems like have no confident to fight the Demon King? Can't he use that mode to fight the Demon King?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mael and the archangels were never meant to be on the Demon Kings level, only on the same level as the Ten Commandments if not stronger, Sunshine is an extremely powerful grace but it still isn't powerful enough to go toe to toe with the demon king.